# Cluster a set of strings based on similarity while optimizing redundancy

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis

The goal is to cluster a set of strings based on similarity while optimizing redundancy.

Example:

```
speed reading freedom
speed reading course
speed reading
speed reading quirky
speed reading quirky today
speed reading engage
speed reading new-wed
speed reading new-born
```

You see `speed reading` as a cluster all have in common, so

```
speed reading
  speed reading freedom
  speed reading course
  speed reading
  speed reading quirky
  speed reading quirky today
  speed reading engage
  speed reading new-wed
  speed reading new-born
```

Now you see `quirky` and `new`

```
speed reading
  speed reading freedom
  speed reading course
  speed reading
  quirky
    speed reading quirky
    speed reading quirky today
  speed reading engage
  new
    speed reading new-wed
    speed reading new-born
```

You could have sorted by `quirky` instead of `speed reading` right from the start.

```
quirky
  speed reading quirky
  speed reading quirky today
...
```

Yet the first version is better as it goes from the biggest commonality to the smallest.

How do you solve that kind of problem in c#?

My idea:
Create a recursive function that ends when the amount of similarity is zero.

```
private void Sorter(int similarity,string content1, string content2)
{
    if (similarity == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(content1);
        Console.WriteLine(content2);
        return
    }
    //Calculate similarity between content1 and content 2
    Sorter() //?
}
```

`similarity` = `How many words content1 and content2 have in common`.

Same words in different order mean the same. Therefore content's words can be ordered alphabetically for easier manipulation.

Comment: You could try split by word, and then use Linq `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` over each word. You might also want to use a tree like data structure.

Comment: Where would _"freedom speed reading"_ fit?

Comment: you've used a single example in your question, but haven't defined what you mean exactly by "similarity" (nor what an `int` representation actually means). what about sentences that contain the same words but in different orders? or where one sentence starts with a different word and then is otherwise identical to another? can you please [edit]() the question with a definition of "similarity"?

Comment: @Flydog57 under speed reading, as it's difference to "speed reading" is one word.

Comment: @RufusL `similarity` = `How many words content1 and content2 have in common`. Same words in different order mean the same. Therefore content's words can be ordered alphabetically for easier manipulation.

Comment: This question has too many degrees of freedom. I have read it a few times and i find it hard to understand what you want to achieve, or by what criteria. Maybe if you can spend some time updating the question and be very specific about your goal, what format you want this in, what the output should be and be explicit the rules about how this should be done...

Comment: @00110001 No. You tell me what you understand first.